# Aggregate function - calculate the mean of each months' variance

Tags: r, datetime, aggregate

I am working with daily data:

```
 > head(data)
    date       X
 01-01-1950   100
 01-02-1950   200
     .         .
 01-01-2015   150
```

Packages that I am using: `TSA`, `ggplot2`, `lubridate`, `xts`, `zoo`

I want to calculate the variance for each month according to this formula:

```
 myvar <- function(Month){
   for (j in 1:(days_in_month(Month)-1)){
     suma = (X[j+1]-X[j])**2 }
   sig = (1/days_in_month(Month))*suma
   return(sig)
 }
```

This outputs:

```
 > myvar(1)
        Jan 
 0.09322581
```

Now I want to aggregate this to calculate the mean of each months' variance. I thought of the following but I don't know how to use the aggregate function here:

```
 data$Month <- month(data$date,label=TRUE)
 data$Year <- format(data$date,format="%Y")
 aggregate( X ~ Month + Year , data , myvar )
```

Expected Result:

First step:

```
 Month  Year   Variance
 Jan    1950   myvar(Jan)
 Feb    1950   myvar(Jan)
  .       .         .
 Dec    2014   myvar(Jan)
 Jan    2015   myvar(Jan)
```

Second step:

```
aggregate( X ~ Month , data , mean )

 Month  Variance
 Jan    myvar(Jan)
  .        .
 Dec    myvar(Jan)
```

** Feb always has 28 days ! No leap years! **

I would like to get the mean of the averages for each month directly (ie step 2) if possible.

Comment: True, it doesn't work. It works however on date so days_in_month(data$date[1]) = 31

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using the [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package to perform the steps you outline:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(date = mdy(date), month = month(date), year = year(date)) %>%
  group_by(month, year) %>%
  summarise(variance = var(X)) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(meanVariance = mean(variance))
```

**Result:**

```
Source: local data frame [1 x 2]

  month meanVariance
1     1         3725
```

**Data used:**

```
data <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "    date       X
 01-01-1950   100
 01-02-1950   200
 01-01-2015   150
 01-02-2015   220")
```

(I added another row to your sample data set so that the variance function wouldn't return `NA` for Jan 2015.)